# NetBeans - SVN - Java WAR

Tags: svn, apache2, netbeans-6.9

I am extremely new to SVN.  I have created my own repository which is running on an apache web server and I am using the NetBeans 6.9.1 IDE to build the Java web application.  I have successfully committed my web application project to my repository using the built in Subversion feature.

Now, what I would like to do is checkout specific revisions of the repository onto my web server (tomcat).  I can do this with the SVN CO command, however, NetBeans is currently only committing the following files/directories.
build.xml
nbproject/
src/
test/
web/

Ideally (I think) I want to commit my web application's WAR file from the dist/ folder, thus deploying the project when I checkout the revision.

I notice when I right click on my project within NetBeans and go to 'Subversion > Svn Properties' there is an svn:ignore statement with the values build & dist.  I am pretty sure this is why the dist folder is not being committed to the repository.

1. Is the best way to commit the WAR file, for later use with a checkout command by committing the dist folder?
   i. If so, how can I remove the svn:ignore statement in the Svn Properties?  I have tried removing it, but it automatically reappears.
   ii. If not, how can I use SVN and my repository more efficiently to update my webapps?

Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't commit files which can be generated from the sources. Or at least, if you really want to commit release files, commit them into a separate tree, disconnected from the dist folder where the war is built and rebuilt during development.

The release should be committed (if it is) only after you've successfully passed all your tests, and you should always create a tag for the whole source tree once you have a release. This way, you can always checkout the tag and rebuild the same release. And you can also easily create a maintenance branch of a released version while working on the next version in trunk.

Comment: Thank you JB.  How would I create a separate tree for the WAR file and ensure it is committed when I commit my project from NetBeans?  Or alternatively, how can I automate the compiling of the source files from my web server (I like the idea of just having to run svn update with or without -r as applicable)?

Comment: Only release to the web server when you have a good set of new features or bug fixes, and when you have passed all the tests (unit, integration, acceptance, performance, etc.). It's a good idea to release often, but it's not to release at every commit. Besides, your SVN repository will very quickly be huge if you commit a whole new war at every commit. If you insist on releasing (to a test server, for example) after every commit, I suggest using a continuous integration server like Hudson, which would detect changes in the SVN tree, compile and run all the tests, and then release if OK.

Comment: Great, thanks JB, that makes more sense!  Up until last year I was still writing my Java apps/web apps in notepad, so i'm just starting to get used to all the great time saving features of the IDE's.  Hudson is another one which I've heard about and never used.. I'll look into it.  Thanks again, +1.